# Using shared memory through tmpfs and NUMA on x86_64/Linux

Tags: linux, tmpfs, mmap, numa

Here's what I'd like to do: put a file on tmpfs but ensure that all of it (all pages of it) ends up on the same NUMA node. First, I thought this would be trivial: I'd just `mmap()` a tmpfs file with `MAP_SHARED` and then use `mbind()` to tie it to the node I want and then I just copy. However, mbind()'s man page explicitly excludes this approach:

```
NUMA policy is not supported on a memory-mapped file range 
that was mapped with the MAP_SHARED flag.
```

Blimey! The `mbind()` man page says that for shared mappings, I can only rely on the process memory policy (using `set_mempolicy()`). But that's far from ideal: I'm running a heavily multi-threaded application and I'd rather not care which thread is doing the copying. I'd rather the memory policy was tied to the tmpfs *file* instead, making my life easier.

Anybody has any ideas on how to solve this problem?